# Vouloir dire charrette?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Il y a une expression que j'entends parfois et dont je ne connais pas l'origine ni la signification (que j'imagine malgré tout être quelque chose du genre "Le travail n'est pas terminé ou bien la situation peut encore changer")
Il s'agit de l'expression "Cela ne veut pas dire charrette".
Quelqu'un a plus d'informations au sujet de cette charrette?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- D'après le livre [Belgicisme](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Bdee07g2wtUC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22%C3%A7a%20ne%20veut%20pas%20dire%20charrette%22&source=bl&ots=WjbjyBaIOZ&sig=5txiUPRpwAfaMcYgOS5d_dOrvLg&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=6ajNUcWqDuX20gWT9IC4AQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA), cette expression signifie "*cela ne prouve rien"*.
- D'après [Les Mots Wallons](http://books.google.fr/books?id=buTuIM1dKEAC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22%C3%A7a%20ne%20veut%20pas%20dire%20charrette%22&source=bl&ots=bSqA01O_N6&sig=bl4YTYUZ66OeG1z-jBDDAr3BySs&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=6ajNUcWqDuX20gWT9IC4AQ&ved=0CHAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A7a%20ne%20veut%20pas%20dire%20charrette%22&f=false), ce serait "*une chose n'entraîne pas nécessairement une autre*", ce qui est assez proche.
- Et personnellement, je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression ici en France

Il semble qu'il s'agit d'un régionalisme. Les Mots Wallons, lié ci-dessus, propose une explication quant à son origine mais j'ignore sa fiabilité.

Comment: Peut-on avoir l'explication dans le corps de la réponse ? (Je n ai pas accès au lien.)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez La source est partiellement en ce qui semble être du vieux wallon, donc je ne suis pas sûr du sens exact, mais de ce que j'ai compris, pendant la terreur les condamnés étaient conduits à la guillotine en charrette. Donc un acte qui "veut dire charrette", c'est un acte qui entraîne la condamnation à mort. À l'inverse, un acte qui ne veut pas dire charrette n'entraîne pas la condamnation.

Answer (score 4):

Des amis architectes (parisiens) m'avait raconté une histoire autour de diverses expressions utilisant le mot "charrette". Mes souvenirs sont vagues, mais voici une tentative de reconstruction.

Cette histoire voudrait que les étudiants architectes devaient rendre leur exercices (un projet d'une longueur à confirmer par les connaisseurs) à quelqu'un qui les ramassaient à l'aide d'une charrette. Du coup, les cris de "charrette" se faisaient retentir pour dire qu'il fallait se grouiller de terminer le projet parce que le temps était écoulé.

D'ailleurs, la page [*Être charrette*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre_charrette) du Wiktionnaire semble confirmer cette anecdote (avec les détails). Il n'y a malheureusement pas de sources citées.

P.S. : je viens de croiser une autre parisienne (mais qui n'est pas architecte) qui semble confirmer avoir entendu des expressions contenant le mot "charrette", pour exprimer le fait d'être (ou non, selon la tournure) à cours de temps ou de ressources.

Comment: +1 C'est une expression qui, en France s'entend  principalement autour des projets d'architecture, mais que j'ai entendu plus rarement dans une équipe informatique ou dans les post-production télé : "Période de travail intensif pour terminer à temps un projet urgent : L'architecte à une charrette ce week-end. Être en Charrette (Le petit Robert)"

Comment: Le sens semble cependant bien différent à celui de l'expression donnée en exemple par la personne qui pose la question. Je connaissais "être charrette" mais je n'ai jamais entendu parler de "Cela ne veut pas dire charrette".

Comment: Il me paraît aussi que l'expression entendue dans la question ait  vraisemblablement une origine belge. Cependant un glissement (ou une fusion) n'est jamais impossible, surtout qu'il existe déjà des dérives vers des expressions moins consacrées que "être charette". Si on admet que "charette" tiens place pour le manque de temps ou de ressource, "cela ne veut pas dire charette" = "cela ne veut pas dire qu'on est à bout de ressource/ que tout est joué". Un peu capillo-tracté certes, mais à langue vivante, rien d'impossible.

Answer (score 4):

J'utilise personnellement cette expression. Et je confirme, c'est bel et bien un belgicisme.

La signification derrière cette expression est : « Ce n'est pas parce que c'est le cas dans une situation donnée que cela le sera forcément dans une autre ». Par extension le « cela ne veut rien dire » ou « cela ne prouve rien » est vrai aussi.

Quant à l'origine de l'expression, ayant lu le [lien](http://books.google.fr/books?id=buTuIM1dKEAC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22%C3%A7a%20ne%20veut%20pas%20dire%20charrette%22&source=bl&ots=bSqA01O_N6&sig=bl4YTYUZ66OeG1z-jBDDAr3BySs&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=6ajNUcWqDuX20gWT9IC4AQ&ved=0CHAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A7a%20ne%20veut%20pas%20dire%20charrette%22&f=false) donné par @Shlublu, voici ce que propose comme piste une des personnes participant à la discussion :

> L'origine remonterait à [l'époque de la Terreur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terreur_%28R%C3%A9volution_fran%C3%A7aise%29) où les condamnés étaient conduits à la guillotine en charrette. Lorsque quelqu'un était réticent à faire une chose, une autre personne pouvait lui répondre « cela ne veut pas dire charrette » ou en d'autres mots « ce n'est pas parce que tu vas le faire que tu risques forcément de te faire guillotiner ! » (ce qui rejoint quelque part la façon dont j'utilise cette expression).

La discussion se termine par cet échange :

> — Si ce n'est pas vrai, c'est bien trouvé ! Mais ce que vous me dites-là…
>   — Je sais bien, cela ne veut pas dire charrette !

Answer (score 1):

Il semblerait que cette expression soit d'origine belge.

La signification la plus proche pourrait être : *"cela ne prouve rien"*.

Par contre, je n'ai pas trouvé grand chose sur ses origines...

Answer (score 0):

Cette histoire, je la connais depuis gosse.
Mon père me l'avait assez répétée. 
C'est un garçon à la messe qui désire avoir une charrue pour labourer son champ. 
Le curé lui dit, que ses vœux seront exaucés que quand il aura récité ses trois pater noster sans se tromper jusqu'au bout. 
Le garçon commence à réciter ses pater. 
Mais, il avait tellement peur de ne pas avoir tout, qu'il s'arrêta et demanda au curé : 
Dite mr. Le curé, 
_est-ce que j'aurai le cheval avec la charrue ? 
Le curé lui répondit, 
Malheureusement, vous n'avez pas fini votre prière jusqu'au bout.

D'où ça veut pas dire charrette. 
C'est pas rien que le fait de le demander qui fait que.

Comment: Je n'ai pas compris le sens de la dernière phrase !

Answer (score 0):

Il y a deux expressions avec charrette:

- Être charrette : être en retard effectivement utilisé en architecture
- Ne pas vouloir dire charrette : qui fait rapport soit avec la terreur soit avec le 
  chevalier de la charrette, Lancelot, de chrétien de Troyes . La charrette était l’équivalent du pilori, l'instrument de la honte.